# JQuery adding click event to a class + alter the css of an event handler

Tags: jquery

I have two divs. One is a button, the other is a box of text. I want to click on the button and trigger the box of the text to reveal itself. I just need to figure out the jquery. I know it's simple, but it's new to me. So far, this is my mark-up.

**HTML**

```
<div class="title">
Piece 1
    </div>

<div class="description">
This is my text.
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title.clicked { background-color:#991B1E; }
.description { display:none; }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        $(this).addClass('title');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `div.description` immediately follows `div.title`, just use `next()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.title').on('click', function () {
        $(this).addClass('clicked')
               .next('.description').show();
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ma4E9/).